# Splitting Groups in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Say I have the following matrix:

```
A(:,1) = [-5 -5 5 5 -5 -5 -5 -5 5 5 5 5]';
A(:,2) = [8 7 3 6 5 9 8 7 9 4 3 2 ]';
```

I'd like to split it into 4 groups based on the signs in the first column (i.e. everything prior to a sign flip is one group):

1) -5 -5
2) 5 5
3) -5 -5 -5 -5
4) 5 5 5 5

and the corresponding grouping in the second column would then be:

1) 8 7
2) 3 6
3) 5 9 8 7
4) 9 4 3 2

My intuition is to use

```
diff(A(:,1)) ~= 0
```

as the first step, but I am unsure how to continue from there. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `accumarray` to create this cell array for you. We first need to assign a unique value to each "group" of consecutive numbers which share a sign. We can then use `accumarray` to place all elements in a given group into an element of a cell array.

```
A = cat(1, [-5 -5 5 5 -5 -5 -5 -5 5 5 5 5], [8 7 3 6 5 9 8 7 9 4 3 2 ]).';

% Compute the sign of each element: -1 for negative, 1 for positive
% Repeat first element for diff
S = sign(A([1 1:end],1));
%   -1    -1    -1     1     1    -1    -1    -1    -1     1     1     1     1

% Compute element-by-element differences
D = diff(S);
%   0     0     2     0     -2     0     0     0     2     0     0     0

% Convert to a logical matrix which will make any non-zero 1 and any zero stays 0
L = logical(D);
%   0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0

% Take the cumulative sum (and add 1) to give each group of elements a unique number
subs = cumsum(L) + 1;
%   1     1     2     2     3     3     3     3     4     4     4     4

% Use this as the first input to accumarray and perform a given action on all elements in 
% A(:,2) which share these values. Our action will be to convert to a cell array 
result = accumarray(subs, A(:,2), [], @(x){x}); 

%   result{1} =
%       8     7
%
%   result{2} =
%       3     6
%
%   result{3} =
%       5     9     8     7
%
%   result{4} =
%       9     4     3     2
```

If we really want to reduce it so a single line we could do this.

```
accumarray(1 + cumsum(logical(diff(sign(A([1 1:end],1))))), A(:,2), [], @(x){x})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
result = mat2cell(A(:), diff([0; find([diff(sign(A(:))); true])]));
```

This uses [`mat2cell`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to split `A` into pieces and put each into a cell. The length of the pieces is computed using [`sign`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sign.html) to detect the sign and then [`diff`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) and [`find`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to obtain the run lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
groupsSizes= diff([0;find(conv(A(:,1),[1,-1],'same')~=0)]);
firstGroup = mat2cell(A(:,1),groupsSizes,1);
secondGroup = mat2cell(A(:,2),groupsSizes,1);
```